# Cassandra Spark Connector latest version how to get

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

What is the newest version of Cassandra Spark Connector. Based on on the website
[spark-cassandra-connector](https://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) **latest is 1.63**.

Based on the compatiblity matrix on [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) need **Connector ver 2 for Sparks2**. So where do we find the Connector 2 version? Is it out there yet?

Connector   Spark     Cassandra       Cassandra Java Driver
2.0          2.0    2.1.5*, 2.2, 3.0    3.0
1.6          1.6    2.1.5*, 2.2, 3.0    3.0
1.5       1.5, 1.6  2.1.5*, 2.2, 3.0    3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a milestone release for 2.0 out. Compatible with Spark 2.0

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.0.0-M3

Comment: thanks, and even much more for the jar file. I was going thru the SBT hell trying to compile from git. I got 1273 errors (only). **Somebody needs to dumb down the compile instructions on git**.

Comment: The SCC compile instructions? 
`./sbt/sbt assembly`?

Comment: I have sbt and Scala 2.10.5, jdk8 installed, downloaded latest from git. running on windows, it errors out :                                                                     
`\spark-cassandra-connector-master>sbt/sbt assembly`                              
`Using snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots for snapshots
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 128
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)  ..... Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? r`

Comment: You need to clone the repository, not just download it

Comment: I just downloaded the repository an unzipped (no cloning). Ran the command from the root **spark-cassandra-connector-master** `\spark-cassandra-connector-master>sbt/sbt assembly` . But the instructions are **In the root directory** run   `sbt assembly` . I tried many ways - different degrees of failure.

Comment: the original link you provided was for the java or the scala connector? Understand 2 separate ones and the names of jars are the same(?). What is the 'embedded connector'

Comment: Git cloned but same error  `C:\git\spark-cassandra-connector>sbt/sbt assembly`  **Error:**          ` [info] Set current project to root (in build file:/C:/git/spark-cassandra-conne
tor/)
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Not a valid command: /
[error] No valid parser available.
[error] /sbt
[error]  ^`

Comment: Finally it worked: `C:\git\spark-cassandra-connector>sbt assembly` It has created [info] Packaging **C:\git\spark-cassandra-connector\spark-cassandra-connector\target\full\scala-2.10\ spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.0-M3-75-g306c125c.jar

Answer (score 0):

I am not a sbt or a scala person. But based on this I think it all depends where you run your sbt command from (the directory). If you have sbt installed and in PATH you can run sbt from anywhere. The confusion (still) for me is which/where sbt to run. As there is a sbt file in /sbt directory (that you get from git). 
Dir structure is

```
C:\git\spark-cassandra-connector
  \spark-cassandra-connector
     \src
  \sbt
   sbt
```

The command I ran that finally worked:

```
C:\git\spark-cassandra-connector>sbt assembly
```

This was actually [per instructions](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/12_building_and_artifacts.md):
" **In the root directory run**

```
sbt assembly
```

A fat jar will be generated to both of these directories:

spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-{binary.version}/
spark-cassandra-connector-java/target/scala-{binary.version}/

Select the former for Scala apps, the later for Java.  "

But I got only 1 jar file.

I did not have (get) spark-cassandra-connector-java/  so did not ultimately get the java .jar file generated(??)

Lets see if it works.